# Установка TortoiseHg. Lubuntu 12.04. Неудовлетворённые зависимости?

Tags: ubuntu

Мои действия:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases
...
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases
...
$ sudo apt-get update
...
$ sudo apt-get install tortoisehg tortoisehg-nautilus
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 tortoisehg : Зависит: mercurial (< 3.2~) но 3.3.2-1ppa2~precise1 будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

Как исправить зависимость?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Виной была банальная невнимательность. В системе уже был установлен mercurial 3.3.2. Снес, а tortoisehg сам подтянул нужную версию.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо `ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases` добавить `ppa:mercurial-ppa/stable-snapshots`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/stable-snapshots
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tortoisehg tortoisehg-nautilus
```

Comment: Приходила в голову такая идея. Пробовал 'stable-snapshots'. Все равно получал неудовлетворенную зависимость.